# Problems in elbow while hitting a forehand shot

Tags: tennis, technique

I coach a player who, before the forward swing, is raising her elbow up.

What drills or changes in technique could I use to correct this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple possible solution is to have the player focus on having the racquethead point upwards at the beginning of the swing. This is impossible with a raised elbow.